# How to get around vue router infinite redirection error?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Getting this error as I want to check in router.beforeEach if there is a sessionToken already in storage and if not then redirect to Login where I could retrieve it:

```
Detected an infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/" to "/login". Aborting to avoid a Stack Overflow. This will break in production if not fixed.
```

My code in router.js

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(ENV == 'development') {
    let sessionStorage = storage.sessionStorageGet('_sessionToken')
    if (sessionStorage === null) next({ name: 'Login' })
    else next()
  } 
})
```

Comment: In this case, for login page you also check **_sessionToken** (this lead to infinite loop), instead, you should define which route require **_sessionToken**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import('../views/login'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: false
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/private',
    ... private route config,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
];

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (ENV == 'development') {
    
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      const sessionStorage = storage.sessionStorageGet('_sessionToken')
  
      if (sessionStorage) {
        next();
      } else {
        router.push({ name: 'Login' });
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
});
```